# Removing border from first-child

Tags: css, responsive-design

Is it possible to remove the first transparent border-left without increasing the height of the first box? I initially tried using margins, but this cannot work due to the use of percentages. Here is what I have - http://jsfiddle.net/KCbgM/1/

Update: The border that I am trying to remove is already transparent - the left border of the first box. I am trying to get the boxes to fit in the 100% with no gap before the first child - which at the moment is a transparent border using the '.grid ul li .grid-item' class.

HTML:

```
<div class="grid">
    <ul>

        <li>
            <div class="grid-item grid-five">
                <div class="grid-person-wrapper">
                    <img class="grid-person-mug" src="http://boardingarea.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/deltapoints/files/2012/07/test.jpg">
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="grid-item grid-five">
                <div class="grid-person-wrapper">
                    <img class="grid-person-mug" src="http://boardingarea.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/deltapoints/files/2012/07/test.jpg">
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="grid-item grid-five">
                <div class="grid-person-wrapper">
                    <img class="grid-person-mug" src="http://boardingarea.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/deltapoints/files/2012/07/test.jpg">
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="grid-item grid-five">
                <div class="grid-person-wrapper">
                    <img class="grid-person-mug" src="http://boardingarea.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/deltapoints/files/2012/07/test.jpg">
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="grid-item grid-five">
                <div class="grid-person-wrapper">
                    <img class="grid-person-mug" src="http://boardingarea.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/deltapoints/files/2012/07/test.jpg">
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>

    </ul>   
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .grid {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        border:1px solid #000;
    }

    .grid ul {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .grid ul li {
        display: inline;
        text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
    }

    .grid-five {
        width: 20%;
    }

    .grid-item {
        float: left;
        display: block;
        background: transparent;   
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;  
    }

    .grid ul li .grid-item {
        border-left: 34px solid transparent;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .grid ul li:first-child .grid-item {
        margin-left:0px;
    }

    .grid-person-wrapper {
        border: 8px solid #cad7c5;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        background: #fff;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
        width: 100%;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: block;
        -webkit-transition: All 0.1s ease;
        -moz-transition: All 0.1s ease;
        -o-transition: All 0.1s ease;
        -ms-transition: All 0.1s ease;
        transition: All 0.1s ease;
    }

    .grid-person-wrapper:hover {
        border: 8px solid #a9f001;
        opacity: 0.8;
    }

    .grid-person-mug {
        width: 100%;
        border: none;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: So I may not have understood the problem here - do you want to remove the spacing between the images, but keep the images the same size (as if they did have a space/border between them)? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to remove the transparent border-left from the first child.

Comment: I have updated my answer - I think that is what you are looking for...

Answer (score 3):

Remove the transparent borders, and instead set `text-align:justify;` on the list and use a pseudo element to stretch contents to 100% width:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/KCbgM/9/)**

### (Relevant) CSS

```
.grid ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align:justify;
}
.grid ul:after {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.grid ul li {
    display: inline;
}

.grid-five {
    width: 18%;
}
```

Comment: Nice - but suppose the OP wants to keep the original spacing and gap after the last item?
(design-wise I wouldn't, which is why I like your solution).

Comment: Actually, I've just noticed that the spaces between each box change in width depending on what device or view port is being used, so this is not fixing one issue but making another.

Comment: @user2965429 - but you can't have fixed spacing between the boxes, fixed sizing for the boxes *and* have a fluid container. If you want a fluid container, something has to allow expansion/contraction...

Comment: I don't want fixed sizes for the boxes. Look at the CSS above, the boxes are fluid.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this...

[Fiddle here..](http://jsfiddle.net/KCbgM/2/)

```
.grid ul li:first-child .grid-person-wrapper
 {
    border-left:transparent;
 }
```

If your requirement is different then let me know..

Good Luck...:)

Comment: The border that I am trying to remove is already transparent. I am trying to get the boxes to fit in the 100% with no gap at the front - which at the moment is a transparent border.

Comment: I'm curious who upvoted this, seeing as the result is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

<del>Try:</del>

<del>.grid ul li .grid-item {</del>

<del>padding-left: 34px;</del>

<del>-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;</del>

<del>-moz-box-sizing: border-box;</del>

<del>box-sizing: border-box;</del>

<del>}</del>

EDITED:

Ok, now I see the issue.

This should solve the problem:

```
.grid ul li:first-child .grid-item {
    margin-left:-34px;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this solves his problem. He wants to remove the first border. even if this is replaced with the padding, it's the same result on removal.

Comment: `without increasing the height of the first box?` unfortunately this will still occur.

Comment: I'm curious as to who downvoted my first answer, seeing as the goal at that point was less than clear...

Comment: the edited answer here provides the desired results : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aaronmallen4/KCbgM/10/), however I think the real problem lies in the structure of the code to begin with.  Any particular reason we're using border instead of margin to provide spacing?

Comment: I would guess perhaps the level of CSS/design experience. Borders are a pretty obvious choice when you don't realise they are meant for enclosing/highlighting an item rather than spacing it out. Of course I could be totally wrong...

Comment: There is still a big space on the right. And I'm using borders because using margins didn't allow the boxes to span the width of the container without moving the end box to the next line.

Comment: @user2965429 You might want to look into using a pre-excisting framework like bootstrap. It would seem to me you're trying to create a responsive layout and bootstrap could definitely help you out with that.

Comment: In that case you should use the answer from @Danield although the spacing will be slightly different.

Comment: This just moved the space to the other side. I don't think this can be done. And I don't really want to use Bootstrap as I'm already using a Wordpress theme, and to include BS might be like crushing a peanut with a steamroller? Seems OTT to include BS just to remove that one space.

Comment: Daniels solution fixed it but created another, it meant that the gaps between would not be uniform when viewed on different view port sizes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to address the `width` change also. Try :

```
.grid ul li:first-child .grid-item {
    border-left: none;
    width: 15%;
}
```

**Fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/KCbgM/5/

Edit 1 :

How about changing the margin between the `divs` to account for the variation ?

```
.grid ul li .grid-item {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    border-left: 34px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    margin-left: 1.25%;
}

.grid ul li:first-child .grid-item {
    border-left: medium none;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 15%;
}
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/KCbgM/6/

Let me know if this is what you want.

Comment: No, this just moves the space over to the other side of the five boxes. The five boxes need to fill the width of the container.

Comment: @user2965429 : Trying to understand your problem, What difference does it make if the border transparent remains as per your original css?

Comment: The goal is - the five boxes must be the same width and height + the gap in between them must be the same (34px) + the five boxes must span 100% width of the web page/container they are in. It's a simple goal but not easy to achieve. Does that make sense?